# checkbox click works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I have this code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  alert('2');
})
```

It works great, every time when I click a checkbox, I get an alert.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  alert('2');
  $("#fresh-table").bootstrapTable("refreshOptions", {
    detailView: false,
  });
})
```

When I add the following, it works also great, but the alert works only one time.
How do I fix this?

EDIT

Used the function onColomnSwitch to fire the event multiple times.
Fixed, tnx!

Comment: Does the checkbox get removed and added back, eg through setting some element with new html? If so you will need to re-set the event listener each time or use a delegated event listener

Comment: That I don't know actually, it's part of the bootstrap-table, but I don't think so. the events just stop giving an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have included the js file for "BootStrapTable" or not. If not included then it will show an error in the console.

I have checked the code and it's working for me. You can try out this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      alert('2');
      $("#fresh-table").bootstrapTable("refreshOptions", {
        detailView: false,
      });
    })
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="test_cb" id="test_cb"> <label for="test_cb">Test Checkbox</label>

<table border="1px solid black" id="#fresh-table">
    <tr><th>Name</th><td>Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Email</th><td>example@gmail.com</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tnx for helping but this only works once... Every checkbox I click after that does not give the alert. I have given up on this, I now use the function onColomnSwitch that does fire everytime I click a checkbox.